# The naturals order question

Tags: set-theory

When it comes to proving $$m < n \implies$$ there exists $$k ∈ N_0$$ such that $$m + k = n$$

where $k, m, n ∈ $ the naturals defined in the von Neumann construction

where $m<n$ is defined as $m$ being strictly a subset of $n$

and where $k+m=s_k(m)$ by the recursion theorem.

I am trying to do induction but I am getting stuck when it comes to defining $k$ with regards to the order. My problem is that I don't know should I define it as $k\in n,k\notin m$? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proven by induction on $n$. Let $m$ be any arbitrary natural.

Note that the first number $n$ that is greater than $m$ must be its successor. So for the base case it suffices to choose $n=m^{+}$. Well then $m^{+}=m+1$, hence $k=1$.

Now suppose that this property holds for some $n$, that is for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $m+k=n$. Now we must show that it is also true for $n^{+}$. Well, $$n^{+}= (m+k)^{+} = m + k^{+}$$
Since $k\in \mathbb{N}$, naturally $k^{+}\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence we can say that there is some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m<n \Rightarrow m+k=n$ for all $n$. Note that our choice of $m$ was arbitrary, and hence it works for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note also that there is no need to define $k$ in terms of the order, however the recursive definition of addition was used to conclude $(m+k)^{+}=m+k^{+}$.